# Bash history is not stored in cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, cmder

I'm using [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) with [cyginw](https://www.cygwin.com/) and [cmder](https://cmder.app/). If I type `logout` to close a bash tab in cmder the history is written to the `~/.bash_history`. If I close the cmder tab or window by any other mechanism, like hitting the X-Button or shuting down the laptop, the history gets lost.

Is there a solution to this? Maybe updateing `~/.bash_history` continously or somehow hooking into the window/cmder close/suthdown proces?

Comment: you can run `history -w` before closing. or use something like `PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'`.

Comment: I don't know what signal bash receives when you close the window. If it is a signal you can catch, you could write a `trap` for this signal and inside the trap have the history written.